# Ubuntu won't boot after update

Tags: boot

Ubuntu won't boot after update. I am using version 18.04.

I tried to boot with the nomodeset key, but it does not help, unfortunately. The problem is aggravated by the fact that I cannot log into the terminal using my login. I don't know why... I login to the tty correctly, but nothing happens. They don't even ask me for a password. In Recovery mode, the operating system starts up, but I don’t understand what and how to do there.

Comment: If the system won't boot, how do you get to a terminal?

Comment: Since Ubuntu 18.04 support here ends in 12 days, it's a good opportunity to back up your data and install a newer release of Ubuntu.

Comment: Organic Marble
I meant connecting to tty using Ctrl+Alt+F2/F3